# Why won't one part of my SVG icon respond to html embed styling, but the other will?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, webflow

I uploaded a custom SVG icon to Webflow and I am trying to use the Webflow interface to change the color using font color, but only part of the icon will change. I have done this easily with "Feather" stock icons in the past. But it's not working with my custom icon made in Illustrator. [Here's the direct link to the icon.](https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5c1000dd4a45852cc0a84c82/64f24244a744873899cac3c4_Fast-Weigh%20Road%20Web%20Icon%20-%20black.svg)

Here is the code I'm working with:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 27.8.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:currentcolor;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M2.1,5.9v5c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7,0c7.7,0,14.5,3.4,19.1,8.7V6.5C15.5,2.1,7.4,2.8,2.1,5.9z"/>
        <path d="M20.9,0.1H3.1c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3v17.9c0,1.7,1.3,3,3,3h17.9c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3V3.1C23.9,1.4,22.6,0.1,20.9,0.1z M21.9,19.7
            c-4.6-5.3-11.5-8.7-19.1-8.7c-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.7,0v-5c5.3-3.1,13.4-3.8,19.9,0.6V19.7z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st1" d="M3.2,8.1c-1,0.2-1,0.2-2,0.5"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M10.3,7.9c-1-0.1-2.6-0.1-3.6-0.1"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M18.3,10.5c-1.4-0.9-2.8-1.4-4.4-1.9"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M22.9,15c-0.5-0.9-1.2-1.7-1.9-2.4"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I was able to successfully change the stroke to currentColor, which did allow me to use the Webflow interface to style the little dashes in the middle. But the rest of the icon is remaining black no matter what I change. I tried setting all the fills to currentColor, but obviously that just gave me an unwanted background color.

I'm not an experienced coder, just an amateur. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second path, the one without a class is filled black. Black is the default. In order to change the color use the fill attribute. You can also style the fill of the path in css